# Display new data on php Back Button

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, session-variables

I am using CodeIgniter.

I have a page (p1) where user enters x-number of fields.
Then, the data is sent to the controller through post, where it is stored in session, then the user is sent to another page (p2).

After user fills out the data on p2, all of the data from p1 and p2 are saved in the DB and a new object is created.

The content of p1 is editable, so when user from his account chooses to edit the page, he is sent to p1 with all the fields filled out. He edits the fields, then goes to p2, but then clicks the back button, because he forgot some fields, and when he is redirected back to p1, the values are the same as if he just entered the page from his account (old values).

However, if I click the back button, and THEN refresh the page, then the values of the session are properly displayed. Can I somehow overcome this?

In my php document I use the following logic:

```
// pass data to p1 from controller as an array
// I check if an object has been passed to the page, if yes, assign values, meaning it is editing. Else, it is a new object
<?php if(isset($objects) && is_array($objects)){ 
         foreach ($objects as $key => $value){
              $id = $value -> id;
              $title = $value -> title; 
      ... } ?>

//Then I do a check - if session values for title exist, then that means user is coming back from the next page, so use session values

<?php if($this->session->userdata('title') != "-1" && $this->session->userdata('title') != "" || $this->session->userdata('title')){
      $id =$this->session->userdata('title');
      $title = $this->session->userdata('title');
...    }

//Then I display the values to the user
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $title; ?>" name="title" id="title" />
```

Answer (score 0):

When the back button is pressed, by default the browser loads the page from cache (this is why its so quick).

If you want the page to be reloaded from the server (so the new session variables display), then you will need to set a no cache header:

```
header("Cache-Control: no-store, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
```

Im not a regular CodeIgnitor user, but i believe the correct way to do this in CI would be to use `$this->output->set_header();` in your controller:

https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/output.html

Failing that, you can use some javascript - save the form values into local storage on submit, then reload them on pageload:

```
<body onload="pageLoad();">
<form action="http://www.google.com" onsubmit="savedata(this);">
    <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" value="default"/>
    <button type="submit"> submit</button>
</form>

<script>
    function savedata(form){
        localStorage.setItem('fname', form.fname);
        return true;
    }

    function pageLoad(){
        if(localStorage.getItem('fname')){
            document.getElementById('fname').value = localStorage.getItem('fname');
        }
    }

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

You should use event listeners rather than inline `on*` attributes, but this is just a quick example to show you

Comment: I tried to put these headers:
$this->output->set_header("Expires: Tue, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT"); 
   $this->output->set_header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT"); 
   $this->output->set_header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0"); 
   $this->output->set_header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false); 
   $this->output->set_header("Pragma: no-cache"); 
and the Cache warning came up.

Comment: That was the initial solution. The problem is that JS was sometimes failing and the result was inconsistent.

Answer (score 0):

You can force the browser to fetch fresh content by turning off cache.
Set these PHP headers on page "A" to prevent caching and force a page reload:

```
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); //HTTP 1.1
header("Pragma: no-cache"); //HTTP 1.0 older browsers
header("Expires: Mon, 01 Jan 1990 05:00:00 GMT"); // Set a date in the past
```

The potential downside is that the browser will display a message to the user that the data needs to be refreshed requiring the user to click to accept to continue. You can read more about caching, in general, and the Warning Header here: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec13.html#sec13.

It is the no-store directive that causes the refresh warning to display. You can remove that, but then there is a chance that the browser will still display from cache if it believes that the content of the page has not changed. In essence, no-cache doesn't REALLY stop the page from being cached, it just makes an effort to reload the page if the browser thinks the data is stale. You can try without the no-store directive first to see if you get your desired results.

Comment: I did try that method before and even though it works, the warning is horrific. It would scare the user and insted of continuing, I am afraid he will just close the page.

Comment: Is there another alternative?

Comment: This looks like it might work for you. The example has some ASP code but you can easily make that PHP. Also you will want to change the ALERT() to call page reload instead. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/696526/Solution-to-Browser-Back-Button-Click-Event-Handli

Comment: But how does this solve my problem? I will just know that my page has went back. p1 still doesn't know about it, so it will display old data.

Comment: Did you read the entire article? Down towards the end it discussions setting session vars and checking those vars on the page that you navigated back to. I probably confused you when discussing the ALERT code. I shouldn't have mentioned that. My bad. Read the article to the end.

Comment: Well, the PageBack functionality is on p2. If I do this check on p2, I already know he is clicking back. If this function is on p1, then it won't work, because the page is cached. Have I overlooked something?

Comment: You are setting the session var on page 2 and checking it on page 1. I think you should try it and see what you get. It looks like it solves your problem because if the sesison var is set you will refresh the P1 page

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to all, who tried to help, but I found the solution which works and was not suggested here.

The initial problem is that when I send data to the page from the controller, I am using POST, and everytime when I come back to the page using a back button, this POST uses the old values to display, which is why the session values did not update. Only after a page refresh did a new POST come through and saw that SESSION overrides some data.

A simple refresh (through php or js) could not solve the problem because it does a forced refresh, which automatically declines the POST sent from the previous page, saying that it has no data coming in at all.

The solution is NOT TO SEND a POST to the page, but rather use a redirect to p1 and before navigating setting all your session values to whatever you need. Then, when you navigate to p2 and click back, if your session values have been updated, the updates will come into effect right away.

Hope this helped.